# Default length of the IDE-generated dash line

Tags: c++builder

In C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin, where can I set the default width of the
IDE generated *dash line* (please see highlighted part in the picture below) when adding a new event handler for example?

I changed the default right gutter from 80 to 100/120 columns and it would be nice, if this line length would be consistent to that by default.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator you are referring to is not generated dynamically, so you can't simply configure its width.  It is actually stored in a template file (`$(BCB)\Bin\bcb.bcf`) and gets copied as-is into the code.  If the template does not exist, the dashed divider is used by default, and it has a fixed width..

So, you would have to edit that template file to create the effect you are looking for.

From [Customizing C++Builder](http://www.backslash.com.au/resources/cppbuilder/customization.htm) (which is written for older IDEs, but some of its information still applies):

> **File and Function Divider Line**
>
> If you don't like the standard line inserted at the top of each units cpp file or the function divider line that is used when an event handler or other function is added to your code by C++Builder then you can set your own. Using lines that stand out for you and which complement your other code comments can help to partition a unit in your head when browsing code.
>
> Specifying a custom top line or function divider line involves editing the file `$(BCB)\Bin\bcb.bcf`, where `$(BCB)` is the folder in which C++Builder is installed. This is a text file in an INI format, so you can use Notepad, WordPad, or any other text editor. There will be no standard text editor associated with the `.bcf` file so you will need to select one when opening the file with Windows Explorer. Alternatively you can start your text editor and browse to the file.
>
> To specify a custom top line in new unit cpp files add a definition for `Divider Line Break` within a new section named `Code Formatting`. To specify a custom function divider line add a definition for `Divider Line`. Set these definitions to the text to be used in the source code. The text should be formatted as a comment so as not to cause syntax errors in your code. The following example demonstrates these customizations.
>
> ```
> [Code Formatting]
> Divider Line Break=/* ===================== TOP LINE ===================== */
> Divider Line=/* ===================== END FUNCION ===================== */
> ```

If the file does not already exist, simply create it.  You will need to run your text editor with administrative rights to save the file if C++Builder is installed under `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` (which it is by default).

Comment: The file usually doesn't exist. It should be placed in the *bin* subdirectory of the installation.